# What would you call the "colleagues" of someone in a cohort (specifically educational context)?

Tags: single-word-requests

If the cohort was an employer, colleague would be correct, but what might the equivalent for a cohort in an educational sense?

> *"I find the degree's coursework challenging, as do my ______________ (**colleagues**?)."*

Comment: Could you please elaborate on just quite what you mean here by “cohort”? It’s not an especially common word, and not everyone may understand it in the way that you do.

Comment: @tchrist it's the name given to people within a group, that share something in common. So if you're on a course, your cohort is the group of people who are studying with you.

Comment: Is the sentence said by a student or a teacher? If the latter, *colleagues* is appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word **peers** might be appropriate here if you really need a single word.

Comment: I think this is the best word in this case, if there's nothing specific. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

That would be a ***classmate***.

ODO:

> **[classmate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/classmate)**
>
> *NOUN*
>
> A fellow member of a class at school, college, or university.

Comment: I did my Masters in a cohort. This is what we called each other.

Answer (score 1):

Cohortians is the technical term but students, fellows, and collegues are acceptable too.

Comment: This is a rare word, not found in the dictionaries I consulted, but is used in technical contexts, and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohort_(educational_group))

Answer (score 0):

I would say **my fellow students** or **the other students**, or whichever noun is appropriate to describe your role.

Comment: Agreed, but I need it to be a single word unfortunately!

Comment: @Daniel: OK why?